# how to load folders names in a directory to an observable collection?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on an app that extracts Zip files containing images into the app local folder and calls them themes.

I have an ObservableCollection in my app. in the MainPage I have this code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Theme> Themes = new ObservableCollection<Theme>();
```

and in its class I have this:

```
public class Theme
{
    public string ThemeName { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage IconImgSource { get; set; }

    public DynamicWallpaper(string name, BitmapImage imgSource)
    {
        this.ThemeName = name;
        this.IconImgSource = imgSource;
    }
}
```

What I need to do is after going to the directory below:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder themeFolder = await localFolder.GetFolderAsync("Themes");
```

is to scan the names of subfolders and adds the name of that folder alongside an image indicating that folder to the observablecollection.

```
Themes.Add(new Theme(addedTheme.Name, new BitmapImage(new Uri(addedTheme.Path + "/Thumnail_Day.png"))));
```

addedTheme.Name is the name of the folder(no path)

How can I load all the folders in "Themes folder" into the observablecollection with a press of a button?

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-listing-files-and-folders help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `QueryOptions` which will let you query a folder for subfolders/files.

first get a reference to your `themeFolder` (just like you did above)

now create a `QueryOption` object and use it like this:

```
var queryOption = new QueryOption {FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep};
var themeSubFolders = await themeFolder.CreateFolderQueryWithOptions(queryOption).GetFoldersAsync();
```

now you have a list of sub folders which then you can add to your `ObservableCollection`

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, im still learning
so to catch the subfolders I follow it with:
`foreach (StorageFolder themeSubFolder in themeSubFolders)
    {
        Themes.Add(new Theme(themeSubFolder.Name, new BitmapImage(new Uri(themeSubFolder.Path + "/Thumnail_Day.png"))));
    }`

correct?